# Python scripting for ANSA software

Tags: python, scripting

I am currently working in python scripting for ansa software and i am getting an error  to select particular groups from model browser tab??

I have tried to select parts inside the groups but Im not able to select groups and parts from model browser through the below mentioned code. Give me a suggestion to overcome this error!!

Code explanation:

utils.OpenModelBrowser(currentmaintab='Parts',viewmode='icon_view') :  This will open you model browser window consists of groups and parts of your opened file.

group1=base.Entities(deck,”ANSAGROUP”) : In this step we need to pick one group or parts from model browser. but im unable to select or pick the groups from the above model browser window.

Error: unable to select items/group/parts from model browser window

```
import os
import ansa 
from ansa import *
deck=constants.NASTRAN
def main():
   utils.OpenModelBrowser(currentmaintab='Parts',viewmode='icon_view')
   group1=base.Entities(deck,”ANSAGROUP”)
   group2=base.Entities(deck,”ANSAGROUP”)
   base.Or(part1)
   base.Neighb(“2”)
   base.Not(part1)
   shells=base.CollectEntities(deck,part2,”SHELL”,True,True)
   base.Or(shells)
   base.Neighb(“1”)
   shells1= base.CollectEntities(deck,None,”SHELL”)
   base.Not(shells1)
if_name_==‘main’:
   main()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.  Could you add the error message you are getting to the question?  It'll help people understand what the problem is so they are more likely to help.

Comment: hello @morric now, I have explained you in detailed. pls check the post now.

Comment: That's much more informative!  I can't help you with that one myself, but hopefully the extra info will mean someone else will have an idea of what is going on.  You might find this post helpful for narrowing down your question to a specific code problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

@Hayabusa you have to use base.PickEntities to select any item in between script run.

```
import os
import ansa 
from ansa import *
deck=constants.NASTRAN
def main():
   utils.OpenModelBrowser(currentmaintab='Parts',viewmode='icon_view')
   group1=base.PickEntities(deck,”ANSAGROUP”)
   group2=base.PickEntities(deck,”ANSAGROUP”)
   base.Or(part1)
   base.Neighb(“2”)
   base.Not(part1)
   shells=base.CollectEntities(deck,part2,”SHELL”,True,True)
   base.Or(shells)
   base.Neighb(“1”)
   shells1= base.CollectEntities(deck,None,”SHELL”)
   base.Not(shells1)
if_name_==‘main’:
   main()
```